# scala convert List(Some()) to List(string)

Tags: scala, scala-collections

how to convert a scala list of some types to list of strings
Ex :

```
List(Some(1234), Some(2345), Some(45678))
to  List("1234","2345","45678")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can go for this:

```
scala> List(Some(1234), Some(2345), Some(45678)).flatten.map(x => x.toString)

res11: List[String] = List(1234, 2345, 45678)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can, as already suggested, `flatten` the collection and then `map` the `toString` method over its items, but you can achieve the same result in one pass by using `collect`:

```
val in = List(Some(1234), Some(2345), Some(45678))
val out = in.collect { case Some(x) => x.toString }
```

The `collect` method takes a partial function (defined with the `case` to destructure the `Option`) and applies it only to the items for which the partial function is defined (in this case, only `Some`s and not `None`s).

You can read more about `collect` [on the official documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.5/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#collect[B](pf:PartialFunction[A,B]):List[B]).

You can run an example and play with it [here on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/nXVF5wzGTIyDHEWtv23qcQ).

Answer (score 2):

```
val str: List[String]= List(Some(123), 
Some(456), Some(789), None,
Some(234)).flatten.map(_.toString)
println(str) // will print List(123,456,789,234)
```

Actually flatten will ignore all the None and take some which we are mapping to string.

Answer (score 1):

```
List(Some(1234), Some(2345), Some(45678)).flatten.map(_.toString)
```

Answer (score 1):

Map and match:

```
li.map {case Some (x) => Some (s"$x")}
res103: List[Some[String]] = List(Some(1234), Some(2345), Some(45678))
```