# List of Option to list of String in scala

Tags: scala, type-conversion, scala-collections

how can we typecast in scala for type parameters?

```
def somefunction[A]():List[A] = {
  //call a webservice and some operation on response that gives list of A
  return list of A
//ex: List(Some(abc2),Some(abc3),Some(232ab))
}

val l1 : List[A] = somefunction;
```

how can we convert type l1 (List[A]) to `List[String]` to get output
like `List("abc2","abc3","232ab")?`

Comment: `result.map(_.toString)`

Comment: it is converting to List("Some(abc2)","Some(abc3"))

Comment: That's what you asked for. If that's not what you want then you'll have to clarify and improve the question.

Comment: I want the out put like  `List("abc2","abc3","232ab")`

Comment: What if `List[A]` is `List[Boolean]`? How should that be converted a `List[String]`? What if `List[A]` is `List[List[Int]]`? Unpacking an `Option[String]` is easy but it only works if `A` is `Option[String]`. If `A` is something else then the same code won't work.

Comment: List [A] is always List[Option[String]]

Comment: `l1.map{case Some(a) =>a.toString}` is giving expected output,is there any better way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you want `None` values to be mapped to `""`, some other default behavior, or to be filtered out of the set entirely? Or are you guaranteed to have only `Some()` values in your list

Comment: yes, there is always some values in the list.

Comment: If `A` is always `Option[String]` then you've asked the wrong question. `A`-to-`String` is different than `Option[String]`-to-`String`.

Comment: If `A` is always `Option[String]` why does that function take a type parameter? why isn't it defined like `def somefunction(): List[Option[String]] = ...`?

Comment: I just given an example of List[A] return type is 
`List(Some(abc2),Some(abc3),Some(232ab))`

Comment: So your return type is List[Option[String]]. What is the input? Where shall the Options of String come from, to be returned? Does somefunction happen to take - let's say a list of - input?

Comment: What is abc2 and so on? The REPL happens to omit Quoting characters for Strings in output, so maybe you mean "abc2".

Comment: that comes from a different operation/function  ex: `ws call`

Comment: What is `ws call`? Your method has no parameters - because you don't know how to specify them, or by intention? It doesn't specify a return value, which is ok, if it can be inferred, but here we can't infer anything, it looks like an x-y-Problem. The last line looks, as if you don't want to pass any parameter, but then the big A notation doesn't make sense.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scala convert List(Some()) to List(string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49883636/scala-convert-listsome-to-liststring)

Answer (score 2):

For something that is always going to be a `List[Option[String]]` try the below

`l1.flatten`

This will strip out the `Some` wrappers, leaving only the contained Strings. If you end up with `None` values however, they will be filtered out of the list, so if you still need those you will need a more complicated process. For instance, if you want to have `None` mapped to empty string (`""`)

`l1.map(_.getOrElse(""))`

Comment: got this error :
`error: No implicit view available from A => scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[B].
           l.flatten`

Comment: What is the type of the object inside your Options? You earlier imply that it will always be String, but your error here implies that it is some other class. Please add the example array into the question, that you are testing on, and getting the error with

Comment: list is a type of [A] ex: `List(Some(abc2),Some(abc3),Some(232ab))`

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function, which takes a List of any type, and via the universal function .toString () return a String:

```
def somefunction[A] (as: List[A]): List[String] = as.map (_.toString) 

scala> somefunction ("foobar".toList)
res113: List[String] = List(f, o, o, b, a, r)

scala> somefunction (List ("foo", "bar"))
res115: List[String] = List(foo, bar)

scala>  somefunction (List (3, 4.4, 1))
res116: List[String] = List(3.0, 4.4, 1.0)
```

Note, that the common supertyp here is double, so 3 is implicitly converted to 3.0 and then returned as String "3.0".

And you can take a List of Option of something and unwrap every element:

```
def somefunction[A] (as: List[Option[A]]): List[A] = as.flatten
somefunction: [A](as: List[Option[A]])List[A]

scala> somefunction (List (Some (4), None, Some (3)))
res112: List[Int] = List(4, 3)
```

But a method, which returns a List of A has somehow to detect, what A is.

You can write a function without parameter, which just returns a constant value:

```
def version () : String = "2.12"
```

but the return type is predefined and here, the value, too. In the next example, the value isn't, but the return type is:

```
scala> def somefunction: Int = scala.util.Random.nextInt (42);
somefunction: Int

scala> somefunction
res117: Int = 21

scala> somefunction
res118: Int = 35
```

In your example, there is an empty parameter list

```
def somefunction[A]() = {
  return list of A
//ex: List(Some(abc2),Some(abc3),Some(232ab))
}

val l1 : List[A] = somefunction;
```

How does somethfunction know that you want a List of Option of String? Where might the values come from?

The big-A notation says, that we have a generic type. A typical method would look like this:

```
def somefunction[A] (a: A) : Option[A] = {
  if (a == null) None 
  else Some (a)
}
```

Or, with more As:

```
def somefunction[A] (a: A, b: A) : List[A] = {
  List (a, b)
}
```

maybe without referring to A in the return type:

```
def somefunction[A] (l: List[A]) : Int = {
  l.size ()
}
```

In `somefunction (List(1, 2, 3))`, A will then refer to Int, in `somefunction (List('a', 'b'))` Char and so on. But without a parameter list, referring to the type A, there is no sense in using A as type parameter.

How else can a method return a - let's say a List of - A, with different type of A, depending on some condition?

A random return type can't be specified that way:

```
scala> def somefunction[A] (): List[A] = {
     |   val ri = r.nextInt (2)
     |   if (ri == 0) List (1, 2, 3)
     |   else List ("foo", "bar")
     | }
<console>:31: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(1)
 required: A
         if (ri == 0) List (1, 2, 3)
                            ^
```

However, A could depend on an outer type:

```
scala> case class Sample [A] (a: A) {
     |   def somefunction (): List[A] = {
     |     List (a, a, a)
     |   }
     | } 
defined class Sample
```

Note that A isn't annotating the method here, only the class, which could be used like this:

```
scala> val sample1 = Sample (1)
sample1: Sample[Int] = Sample(1)

scala> val sample2 = Sample ("two")
sample2: Sample[String] = Sample(two)

scala> sample1.somefunction
res119: List[Int] = List(1, 1, 1)

scala> sample2.somefunction
res120: List[String] = List(two, two, two)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val ans =List(Some(1), None, Some(2), Some(3),None).flatten.map(_.toString)
```

It should do the trick.